# How to detect when interrupted?

Tags: c++, c, interrupt, interrupt-handling

So if I were to write a C/C++ "blocking" (or just a function which may take a long time to execute) function how would I be able to detect if the processing was interrupted so that I could return something like EINTR like calls such as `send` and `recv` do. I have tried searching around and have not figured out how to tell if a call gets interrupted. Or is this something only system calls can do? If so why is that the case?

Comment: That will depend on the blocking function.. Will the function use system calls? If everything is user-space you may just wrap the function inside a class with state.

Comment: Just for shits and giggles lets assume both one with and one without. And lets assume straight C with no classes. Also at that point it still wouldn't make the function return right away even if it was a class with a state, it would still just go right back to executing the function in question no?

Comment: How are you planning to "block" without making a system call?

Comment: Ok so lets assume "block" is a loose term here and its just something that is running in a loop for a long time but not forever.

Comment: You can implement a blocking `recv` using non-blocking `recv` by looping untill you actually recv any data. Something like:

`while(recv(port)==NULL)` 

Are you trying something similar??

Comment: @brokenfoot not really. I am really looking at it from a view of not calling a system call or any other call that would be blocking. Really just doing quite a long bit of work and really want to know if it gets interrupted how I would be able to say that it did and return kind of like a `recv` call does.

Comment: OKay.. I think you are looking for something called `setjump()` and `longjump()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag to indicate that the interruption occurred:

```
volatile std::sig_atomic_t processing_interrupted = false;
```

And an interrupt handler function to set it:

```
extern "C" void interrupt_processing( int ) {
    processing_interrupted = true;
}
```

Install and monitor the interrupt handler as long as it's valid, then uninstall it:

```
int do_processing() {
    processing_interrupted = false;
    std::signal( SIGINT, & interrupt_processing );

    // Do something for a long time.

    // Check flag periodically:
    if ( processing_interrupted ) return EINTR;

    std::signal( SIGINT, SIG_DFL );
    return 0;
}
```